# How to INITIALIZE_UPDATE on SmartCard?

Tags: java, smartcard, globalplatform

New on smartcard here, the information about how to interact with smartcard is pretty scattered on the web...

I looked into the GlobalPlatform API and tried their example, but I don't understand how the `JavaCard` stuff can eventually tie to and interact with an actual card reader... so I end up using `javax.smartcardio` and I am able to get the ATR and then I issued the following command to try to get the Security Domain: `00 A4 04 00 06 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00`

And I get this back as the ResponseAPDU: `6F408407A0000001510000A535732F06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020201630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B0403709F6501FF`

Then I try to send the `INITIALIZE_UPDATE` command which is `80 50 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, after that the card reader blink for a good 45 seconds to 1 minute, and eventually returned `SW: 9000`, however there were nothing in the ResponseAPDU...

From what I've read, I am supposed to be getting some diversify data etc so that I can continue with the initialization of the card... Can someone tell me what is wrong with my command?

And if there is GlobalPlatform API expert here, could they tell me how exactly can I use the JavaCard stuff to eventually communicate with a smart card reader or is not possible? It would be great if is possible, then I could skip all the SecureChannel stuff and use the ones from GP API.

Edit:
I've tried to use the GlobalPlatform's tool gp.exe to just poke the card for basic info, and it still fails.

```
gp -info
Reader: ACS ACR39U ICC Reader 0
ATR: 3BD6970081B1FE451F078031C1521118F9
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BD6970081B1FE451F078031C1521118F9

***** Card info:
Card CPLC:
ICFabricator: 4790
ICType: 6A15
OperatingSystemID: 8231
OperatingSystemReleaseDate: 4176
OperatingSystemReleaseLevel: 0096
ICFabricationDate: 6133
ICSerialNumber: 00001AA0
ICBatchIdentifier: 1424
ICModuleFabricator: 1142
ICModulePackagingDate: 6133
ICCManufacturer: 1143
ICEmbeddingDate: 6133
ICPrePersonalizer: 1144
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate: 6133
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID: 130B0000
ICPersonalizer: 0000
ICPersonalizationDate: 0000
ICPersonalizationEquipmentID: 00000000
***** CARD DATA
Unknown tag: 31
***** KEY INFO
VER:1 ID:1 TYPE:AES LEN:32
VER:1 ID:2 TYPE:AES LEN:32
VER:1 ID:3 TYPE:AES LEN:32
```

then I try to just list the content of the card (is this normal for a blank card?)

```
gp -l
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: STRICT WARNING: Card cryptogram invalid!
Card: FC3F2DC68462F1DF
Host: 5B54B15BCAD52B52
!!! DO NOT RE-TRY THE SAME COMMAND/KEYS OR YOU MAY BRICK YOUR CARD !!!
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.giveStrictWarning(GlobalPlatform.java:207)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel(GlobalPlatform.java:583)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:463)
```

Comment: It feels like you're experience some issues with another process (likely Windows) communicating with the smart card. Could you try and disable the "certificate propagation service" in Windows and see what happens?

Comment: I've disabled `Certificate Propagation` service, but it doesn't change anything, it only gives `9000` and empty ResponseAPDU.

Comment: This is so weird, upon trying a different blank card (same batch), i'm getting this back now, however I'm not sure how to parse this.  `1424613300001AA0010001037078184156DAD68F2CF8426EBB04AB4A9200000E`

Comment: That seems much better; maybe something is wrong with the card after all. The meaning of the response data can be found in the (publicly available / registration required) GlobalPlatform card specifications.

Comment: From the response data, your card uses `scp03` and `non-default` keyset.